# Orleans storage provider DynamoDB, provider not loaded

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb, orleans

I have just created a silo project in visual studio, and installed the orleans silo nuget package. When I then try to use the storage provider AWS DynamoDB, it gives me the following error:

```
[2017-08-21 10:34:07.405 GMT    13      ERROR   103108  ProviderLoader/IStorageProvider 127.0.0.1:11111]        !!!!!!!!!! Provider of type Orleans.Storage.DynamoDBStorageProvider name SHMSDDB was not loaded.Please check that you deployed the assembly in which the provider class is defined to the execution folder.
```

My config file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<OrleansConfiguration xmlns="urn:orleans">
  <Globals>
    <SeedNode Address="localhost" Port="11111" />
    <StorageProviders>
      <Provider Type="Orleans.Storage.DynamoDBStorageProvider" Name="SHMSDDB"
    DataConnectionString="Service=https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com;AccessKey=AKIAIFA4PW6KTJTQDXOA;SecretKey=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;" />
    </StorageProviders>
  </Globals>
  <Defaults>
    <Networking Address="localhost" Port="11111" />
    <ProxyingGateway Address="localhost" Port="30000" />
  </Defaults>
</OrleansConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the dependencies described in the start of the documentation.

The only installed package was the silo host:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Orleans.OrleansHost
```

But in order to use AWS DynamoDB I also needed:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Orleans.OrleansAWSUtils
PM> Install-Package AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 -Version 3.1.5.3
```

I installed it all in the NuGet package manager, once I went through the Orleans Guide again.